# segmentation fault as soon as I launch a Python shell ( Intel python 3.9.16 ) following an upgrade of Intel python 3.9.7 on macOS Ventura

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault, intel-python

I have upgraded my `Intel python` version (from python `3.9.7` to `3.9.16`).

And impossible to launch a shell or execute a pyhton script.

I have executed `python3.9.16` with :

```
    $ python3.9 -v
    
    import _frozen_importlib # frozen
    import _imp # builtin
    import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
    # installing zipimport hook
    import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
    # installed zipimport hook
    # /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-39.pyc matches /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/encodings/__init__.py
    # code object from '/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-39.pyc'

 ...
 

# /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/__pycache__/copyreg.cpython-39.pyc matches /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/copyreg.py
# code object from '/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/__pycache__/copyreg.cpython-39.pyc'
import 'copyreg' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7be006d580>
import 're' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bf0104df0>
import 'typing' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bf00c2d00>
import 'importlib.abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bf00e50d0>
import 'importlib.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bf00e6280>
# possible namespace for /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mpl_toolkits
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7c1008dbb0>
zsh: segmentation fault  python3.9 -v
```

Has anyone already had this kind of error under `MacOS Ventura 13.5` with Intel `Python 3.9.16` ? How to fix it ?

Comment: I've never seen anything like that and I've been using Python on macOS since 2008. You didn't say how you upgrade your Python installation but you probably have somehow managed to get a mixture of files from the old and new version. I would just nuke the current Python install directory and reinstall.

Comment: @KurtisRader .I have upgraded `python3.9` with `conda update` (package `intelpython`)from Intel OneAPI in order to get the last version `python 3.9.16`. I don't understand what is happening

Comment: Please raise a query in **oneAPI Registration, Download, Licensing and Installation** [here!](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/bd-p/registration-download-licensing-instal)